# Why does i3 move my mouse to a different monitor?

Tags: mouse, i3

I am using Arch Linux, and i3wm v4.21.1

I have 3 monitors setup using `xrandr`.
Here's what I am doing, and the expected behaviour:

1. Move my cursor to the monitor I desire to open the application on (in this case steam)
2. Press <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open Dmenu, type `steam`, hit return
3. The Application launches in the monitor the cursor is in.

What actually happens:

1. Move my cursor to the monitor I desire to open the application on (in this case steam)
2. Press <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open Dmenu, type `steam`, hit return
3. The cursor moves on its own (a few seconds after selecting to launch steam) to the primary monitor, and steam launches there.

Why does the cursor decide to jump to another monitor (in this case monitor flagged as primary w/ `xrandr`)? This happens with other applications as well, Steam was just a popular example.

This happens when launching a game from steam as well. I hit play and move my mouse to the monitor I want it to launch on, and the cursor jumps to another (non primary this time) monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an i3 feature called Mouse Warping.

To turn it off, you can set the following in the i3 config file `~/.config/i3/config` (or wherever your i3 configuration file is stored):

`mouse_warping none`

Also worth taking a look at is the `focus_follows_mouse` attribute.

*Refer to the following section in the i3 configuration guide: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_mouse_warping*